# Cannot purchase from Mac App Store ("Connection failure" msg)

Tags: mac-appstore, error

I have a 2008 MBP with 10.7.4. I use a WIFI and ethernet connection. I cannot purchase or download anything in the Mac App store on my computer. I can, using other folk's computers. After putting in the password, I receive a red "Connection Failure" message. Despite this message, I can click on apps in the Store to read about them. I turned off Little Snitch to no avail. Everything else on the internet works just fine. No useful assistance from Apple. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you have trouble both on your computer and others as well?

Comment: No. Only on my computer. No problem on another Mac.

Comment: iAM Don't forget that you can answer your own question, if you found the solution. Say what worked for you and quote from the apple discussions site the information that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: log out of your iTunes account (within the App Store choose Store > Sign Out), restart your Mac and then try to purchase/download something.

Comment: Tried. Didn't work. Very strange problem as I hadn't had problems in the past with the Mac Store. I don't recall installing anything new the would interfere with the store.

Comment: I FOUND the answer at the link below. The only correction I would add is to do EVERY item that has a blue cross. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4085819?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND the answer at the link below. The only correction I would add is to do EVERY item that has a blue cross. 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4085819?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Quote what worked for you from the original source, just in case that link goes away at some point. See how to answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer